# set input width on Svelte Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: css, svelte

I am using this library: https://sveltematerialui.com to render an autocomplete component in Svelte.

I need to style the width of the input. I have been able to attach a style directly on the component inline.

However this will only apply the with to the parent div and not the child input.

Here is a REPEL I created to reproduce the issue: https://svelte.dev/repl/12db54ca23fc497685adf82cafe73bf6?version=3.53.1

This library should be based on Material UI. It's possible that there is a Material UI way to style the input.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple CSS override?

```
...
<style>
    .mdc-text-field__input {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Svelte appends additional characters to classes to avoid style collisions between different components. :global() will override this feature of the Svelte compiler. If you nest the :global() within a class placed on the parent div, you can avoid exposing that CSS selector outside of that Svelte component.

```
.columnsmargins {
            :global(.mdc-text-field__input){
            width: 600px !important; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Related post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69858237/how-to-use-svelte-global-with-sass-scss

Comment: Writing global styles in Svelte: https://dev.to/natclark/writing-global-styles-in-svelte-7he